# Can Javascript function replace own body

Tags: javascript

```
function decode(s) {
  decode = function (s) {
      return s + '!'
  }
  return s+'?'
}
console.log(decode("asd"))//outputs asd?
console.log(decode("qwe"))//outputs qwe!
```

This code will replace function body from within a function. But unfortunately this is not very clean. Because first `decode` is module function scope and second `decode` is global variable scope. Is there another, cleaner way to replace the function body from inside the function?

The usage case example would be that the first time function called it might need to initialize some data. And subsequent calls will only do a decoding.

Comment: It doesn't exactly replace it own body, it reassigns `decode` variable, so going from that you can have function call function stored, for instance, in its own property and replace that.

Comment: I think more readable would be to have `oldFunc` and `newFunc`, the first one will do some stuff then at the end you put `oldFunc = newFunc`. But don't know if this will work, or if the problem is not an actual problem but more like a curiosity if it can be done like you said

Comment: right, but can I really "replace the body"?

Comment: And by replacing the body you mean that your method should return "asd!" on the second call?

Comment: @exebook No but replacing the whole function has the same effect...

Comment: It doesn't affect the global scope on my browser: http://jsfiddle.net/eaNJ9/3/

Comment: @exebook Self-defining functions are just fine and scoping is not an issue. Nothing forces you to declare this function globally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this to make a variable that tracks the number of times the function has been called and do some initialization the first time it's called:

```
var decode = (function(){
  var numCalls = 0;
  var potatos;

  return function(){
    if(numCalls++ == 0){
      // Initialize some stuff here
      potatos = 7;
    }

    // Use stuff here
    console.log(potatos);
    potatos += 3;
  }
})();
```

Comment: That's just inefficiently evaluating an additionnal condition for every invocation. There's nothing wrong about the self-defining function pattern.

Comment: plalax thank you, you are nailing it down, the reason I want to replace the body is to avoid one extra "if" each call.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are using is well known as Self-Defining Functions (or possibly lazy function definition).

Instead, why not use an object with a constructor function,

```
var Decode = function(s){
    var that = this;

    that.property = s;

    that.decode = function(){
        return that.property + "!";
    };
};

var decode = new Decode("asd");

decode.property //"asd"
decode.decode() //"asd!"
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but decode.decode() means one extra object dereference each call and will hurt the performance. The idea to replace the function body is to gain one extra bit of performance.